# Работа с вещественными числами в Assembler

Tags: ассемблер

можно ли работать с вещественными числами в Ассемблере, не используя сопроцессор?

Comment: Можно, но по сути это будет эмулирование "сопроцессора" (точнее, инструкций fpu, сопроцессора как отдельной микросхемы в компьютерах давно уже нет). Также можно через целочисленную арифметику эмулировать вычисления с фиксированной точкой.

Comment: Ну ведь работали же когда-то :) Правда, через соответствующие библиотеки эмуляции, предвычисленные таблицы и т.п.

Comment: На x86/x86_64 для этого сейчас используются скалярные инструкции SSE.